# What exactly does "Safe to leave" mean?

Tags: dota-2

When one of your team members disconnects at the beginning of the game and doesn't come back in certain amount of time, the game is set to "Safe to leave".

I did some research on that subject, and almost everyone has different opinion on it. Some say that when the game is marked as "safe to leave" you wont get an "abandoned" point but will get loss while some say you'll get neither.

So what exactly does "Safe to leave" do? If you leave the "Safe to leave" game and start another, will it count as loss? If you continue playing the "Safe to leave" game and you win, will that win count? If the game gets marked as "Safe to leave," does that means someone from enemy team can leave the game too and not get any loss or abandon point?

In case you don't get neither loss nor abandon point when you leave the "Safe to leave" game, what happens if you decide to stick until the end and you win or lose the match. Will those wins/losses count?

Comment: not 100% sure but I think the win/losses still count.

Comment: @spartacus That's the thing that confuses me. Sometimes the loss didn't count for me because of that, and sometimes it did. It's weird and almost nobody knows how exactly does that system works.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A game becomes *safe to leave* when someone *abandons* it (*abandon* means that the player was disconnected or away from keyboard for 5 minutes, or just pressed Leave Game).

If you disconnect from a game, which is *safe to leave* or will become *safe to leave* before you *abandon* it, you don't get an *abandoned* point. However, you will still get a *win* or *loss* point, depending on how the game ends. Usually this will be a loss, because your team will be much weaker without some players.

If all 5 members of a team *abandon* the game, they automatically lose in a few seconds.

**If someone disconnects from a game and doesn't reconnect before *first blood*, or simply *abandons* it before *first blood*, the game will be *safe to leave* and *no stats will be recorded*, which means that nobody will get a *win* or *loss* point or *battle points*.**

A game will be recorded in your game history even if it's *safe to leave* and *no stats will be recorded*, but don't let that confuse you: that doesn't imply you get points for it.

---

Now I will answer your exact questions and show some more examples.

> If you leave the "Safe to leave" game and start another, will it count as loss?

If "*no stats will be recorded*", nothing will count.
  If it's just *safe to leave*, it will count as a win or loss depending on whether your team won or lost.

> If you continue playing the "Safe to leave" game and you win, will that win count?

If "*no stats will be recorded*", nothing will count.
  Otherwise, a game being *safe to leave* changes nothing in this aspect, and the win will count.

> If the game gets marked as "Safe to leave" does that means someone from enemy team can leave the game too and not get any loss or abandon point?

When a game is *safe to leave*, anyone can *abandon* and not get an *abandoned* point, but they will get a *loss* or *win* unless "*no stats will be recorded*".

- If you leave a game and your remaining team members win, you get a *win* unless "*no stats will be recorded*".
- If someone disconnects from a game that is not yet *safe to leave*, then you disconnect, you will not get an *abandoned* point, UNLESS they reconnect before their 5 minutes run out. (Not entirely sure about this one.)
- If someone disconnects from a game that is not yet *safe to leave*, then you disconnect, then they reconnect and you don't reconnect before your 5 minutes run out, you will be the first one to abandon the game and will get an *abandoned* point.

Answer (score -2):

Negative sir even if it says safe to leave it's not you will get low priority it's a bug going around but oh well what can you do I just stay in game and farm and try not to die.

Comment: This clashes with the accepted answer.  Do you have any sources?

Comment: As a Dota player I can confirm that this is not a bug and the accepted answer is right, 


OP probably got reported multiple times and got low priority just after quitting a safe-to-leave game, just a coincidence. @TimmyJim