# What can cause an abandon?

Tags: dota-2

After playing a couple of games yesterday, my abandon rate went from 0% to 1%. Yet I didn't abandon/rage/disconnect any game. And haven't done so in any of my games.

I did have a game that aborted because someone else failed to load before getting to hero selection. But I've had that happen before and never received an abandon. And I know I was loaded because I was chatting with others while waiting for loaders.

Comment: See also: [What exactly does “Safe to leave” means?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115414/what-exactly-does-safe-to-leave-means/115418#115418)

Comment: I always misread this question as "What can cause an Abaddon?"

Comment: @gitsitgo - The House of Avernus, of course!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You recieve an [abandon](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Stats#Abandonment) if :

- You disconnect from the game and fail to reconnect within 5 minutes (given that the game keeps on playing, if the game is paused, the 5 min are not ticking)
- You disconnect from the game and explicitly click the "Leave Game" button (in the matchmaking menu)
- You spend more than 5 min in the game without earning any experience (the game then conciders you AFK and give you an abandon)
- You have not interacted with the game in the last 2 minutes

You used to recieve a ["secondary abandonment"](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Stats#Party_Abandonment) if one of the member in your party abandoned the game (following one of the condition listed above). Those were displayed between bracket in your DotA profile :

```
Abandon : number of abandon (number of secondary abandonment)
```

But since one of the last patch they are no longer counted and you just have a global % of game abandonned in your profile.

Comment: "You have not interacted with the game in the last 2 minutes" wait what?

Comment: @T_O Well that's quoted from the wiki which is usually up to date with the information. To be honest i was quite surprise myself but it has never happened to me or any of my friend before so I can't confirm. If you want to test feel free to do so :D =p

Comment: So is it possible to finish a game but exit/disconnect from it in a way that's counted as an abandon? Like a say, I've never quit a game intentionally or due to connection problems. And I always remain active to the end. So I don't understand what could have caused this other than the game that aborted due to failed loaders.

Comment: @ScottO When you exit a game you have a message displayed in the menu that tell you if it is safe to leave the game and if it is not safe what are the consequence so I don't see that happening by mistake. Quite frankly, except not earning any XP for 5 min (like being dominated really hard and clustered in your base for 5 min) and having a rare glitch that doesnt dipsplay the abandonment message (double badluck), I don't see what it could have been. Plus after the ancient is destroyed, its alwyas safe to leavevia the exit button in the menu (I do it quite often)

Comment: @WizLiz "Plus after the ancient is destroyed, its alwyas safe to leave via the exit button in the menu (I do it quite often)" That's why I was confused to see I had abandoned > 0%. Any game I've entered - gotten far enough to pick a hero - I've been in until one of the Ancients has been destroyed. Any game I haven't made it to hero picking phase, has been due to failed loaders.

Comment: I dont think that those AFK timers actually work. I had a game the other day where a party of 3 decided to AFK for 20 minutes so they could try their "awesome" comeback skill (didnt work). They were never penalized with abandon.

Comment: @StingyJack Watch the replay and see if any of them didn't win XP (for more than 5 min) or move his/her hero (for more than 2 min), if yes then it might be broken but I've already seen many time the 5 min without XP giving an abandon so I think it works.

Comment: Will you recieve abandon if you suddenly disconnected lets say 1 min before ancient was destroyed?

Comment: "You used to recieve a "secondary abandonment" if one of the member in your party abandoned the game (following one of the condition listed above)." So this might be why I got an abandon. I think I did have a party member rage quit around that same time.