# Early disconnect from all 5 team members (before first blood / 5 minutes)

Tags: dota-2

I have some questions regarding the abandon system in Dota 2:

1. scenario: A player disconnects (not abandons!) the game before first blood / 5 minutes, then all his team members disconnect shortly after, nobody reconnects, the game ends before the first player is 5 minutes disconnected.

   **My questions: Will anyone get an abandon? Will the game count as win or loss for anyone?**
2. scenario: A player abandons the game before first blood / 5 minutes, the game is safe to leave with no stats recorded for everyone else.

   **My questions: Will the abandoning player get a count towards his number of abandons? Will he get a loss?**

I got most info about abandons [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115414/what-exactly-does-safe-to-leave-means) but I'm not entirely sure about these two scenarios.

Comment: The answer to the second question is yet(to both subquestions). Im not sure about the other question but I think the one who leaves first, gets an abandon. The game will count as a loss to the person who abandons. The game wont count for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm almost certain no one will get abandon, but you do get a loss.
2. He will get both an abandon and a loss.

Comment: You are correct, but note that for the first scenario, sometimes the game doesn't end as quickly as it should, so there is still a chance of the first person abandoning.

Comment: @JohntheGreen he said "the game ends before the first player is 5 minutes disconnected."

Comment: He says that, yes, but that doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 0):

1: In order for the game to end the player has to be completely disconnected. (The circle symbol as opposed to the x). So someone will always have to abandon for it to work.